# Microsoft Graph API and Azure AD B2C - order by surname throws

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I use Microsoft Graph API to list users in my Azure AD B2C tenant. When I try to get it ordered by surname (lastname) I get this error:

> Unsupported sort property 'surname' for 'User'.

What's supported is *'displayName'*, which may contain person name in the form of [firstName lastName] or [lastName firstName]. I wonder if there's any way to get the list ordered by last name.

The code, just in case:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest usersRequest = GraphClient.Users.Request()
    .Select(u => new {u.Id, u.DisplayName, u.Mail, u.GivenName, u.UserPrincipalName, u.AccountEnabled, u.Surname}).OrderBy("displayName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use orderby parameter with surname in either standard Azure AD or Azure AD B2C tenants as of now.

You may post a feedback regarding this feature at [Azure Feedback Portal](https://feeback.azure.com), which is monitored by the product team for product enhancements.

Comment: Feedback Portal doesn't work.